# MongoDB - Many counts using an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to make many counts using an array as input in Mongoose, and return an array

I am trying to use the code below but it is not working, `list2` is returning as empty.

```
list = ['Ann', 'Bob', 'John', 'Karl'];
list2 = [];

for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    Clients.count({name: list[i]}, function(err, doc){
        list2.push(doc);
    })
}
return list2
```

Comment: Clients.count() is an asynchronous function. return list2 will be executed before all the db queries are completed, so that count in list2 will not accurate when you consume it. You better learn how to handle asynchronous code via callbacks or promises.

Comment: If you get the data in form of array of objects like this `[ {name:'Ann',Count:1},{name:'Bob',Count:3},{name:'John',Count:5} ]`, Will that be ok for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const async = require('async');

var list = ['Ann', 'Bob', 'John', 'Karl'];

async.map(list, function(item, callback) {
    result = {};
    Clients.count({name: item}, function(err, data) {
        result[item] = data || 0;
        return callback(null, result);
    });
}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could run an aggregation pipeline as follows:

```
list = ['Ann', 'Bob', 'John', 'Karl'];
list2 = [];
Clients.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": { "$in": list } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$name",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "list2": {
                "$push": {
                    "name": "$_id",
                    "count": "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, results) {
    list2 = results[0].list2;
    console.log(list2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way based on Med Lazhari's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41781710/4099593)

```
const async = require('async');

var list = ['Ann', 'Bob', 'John', 'Karl'];

var counting = function (item, doneCallback) {
    var query = Clients.count({name: item});
    query.then(function (doc) {
      return doneCallback(null, doc);
    });  
  };

async.map(list, counting, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```